# Load additional information inside Select2 select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am searching by city names inside select2 function. And I want to provide some additional information about the city based on the on the information I get from the first ajax call, so i need to somehow make another ajax call inside processResult function and write result to "text" parameter. Are there's a way to do that?

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax : {
        url : "https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCities?country_id=2&lang=ru",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        delay : 250,
        data : function(params) {
            return {
                q : params.term,
                page : params.page
            };
        },
        processResults : function(data, page) {

            return {
                results : $.map(data.response, function(item) {
                    return {
                        text : item.title + " " + /*result of another ajax request based on item.cid*/,
                        id : item.cid
                    }
                })
            };

        },
        cache : true
    }
});
```

Comment: If you wish to render the list with more information, you'll need to provide that data in the original response...that will simplify your problem.

Comment: The problem is that first I am receiving the name and id of the city from one URL, and than I need to get city's region by it's id from another URL. And after than I want to print the name and region.

Comment: This is possible using shared references and the templating methods, but your question right now is probably too broad to be answered.